# Fetch NodeMetrics from Telemetry shard

Tags: substrate-node, validator, metrics, telemetry

I want to fetch a couple of node metrics, like `startup_time`, `bandwidth_upload`, `bandwidth_download`, etc for all of the nodes in my network, for the purpose of sending them to another application though a RPC/WS API, as these details are quite hard to read from the `<node-ip>:9615/metrics`. I've managed to get them from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry/blob/master/backend/telemetry_shard/src/main.rs#L343) and save them into a JSON file, but I can't fetch the respective `validator` for those metrics. Is there any other location where I can get all these details for each validator? I've tried looking into the `telemetry_backend` too, but didn't have any luck yet.
Any suggestions in regard will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: do you want to map the nodes to their on-chain accounts?

Comment: Yes @dastansam, Do you have any suggestions for it?